# Compiler error for function return with value set inside of if statement?

Tags: swift

Here's a sample of my code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell : goalTermCell
    if i == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("termCell",
                   forIndexPath: indexPath) asf goalTermCell 
    }
    else if i == 2 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("termCell",
                   forIndexPath: indexPath) as goalTermCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Xcode says the variable is used before being initialized.
I know that this code is dumb, it's just a PoC for learning about UI Tables

Comment: what happens if i > 2 or i < 1 ? - also perhaps a case is better here

Comment: As i said, the code is retarded and makes 0 sense to ever actually apply it. I'm doing this to test cells (cell 1 is prototype 1, cell 2 is prototype 2). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that i could be something other than 1 or 2 and so the compiler sees what happens if it is and in that case cell is not set. In this case then it is returned (i.e. used ) without being set.

In this case I would use a case statement with a default replacing the if.

I note that you code is incomplete as it does not set i anywhere thus this solution might have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
switch i {
case 1:
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
case 2:
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
default:
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBeWheniIsNot1or2
}
```

or

```
if i == 1 {
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
}
else if i == 2 {
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
}
else {
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBeWheniIsNot1or2
}
```

or

```
cell = whatEverYouWantItToBeWheniIsNot1or2
if i == 1 {
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
}
else if i == 2 {
    cell = whatEverYouWantItToBe
}
```

Either way, now in case 'i' happens to be something other than 1 or 2 the cell will still be initialized when it is returned from the function